# How to enable rate limits for outside urls in Istio?

Tags: istio

Following this [task](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/) I can access to external services by defining `ServiceEntry` configurations. And in another [task](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/) I can limit the traffic to a service, it works in cluster. But I failed to limit the traffic from service in cluster to external urls like www.google.com.

This is my adapter configuration

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: memquota
metadata:
  name: handler
namespace: samples
spec:
  quotas:
  - name: requestcount.quota.istio-system
  maxAmount: 15
  validDuration: 10s
```

and quota configuration

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: quota
metadata:
  name: requestcount
  namespace: samples
spec:
  dimensions:
    source: source.labels["app"] | source.labels["svc"] | "unknown"
    destination: dnsName("www.google.com") | uri("https://www.google.com") | "unknown"
```

How to enable rate limits for outside urls in Istio?

Answer (score 2):

You should [direct the traffic through an egress gateway](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/egress-gateway/), and then apply the rate limiting. The issue is that in Istio, policy enforcement is performed by the destination. In case of the external services, they are represented by an egress gateway.

Comment: I have tried that task, but it's still not working. I don't know if my configuration is correct.

Comment: Let me write documentation about it during the weekend.

Comment: Could you give me some hints about that documents? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote a question in istio/istio https://github.com/istio/api/issues/509. I will follow the issue.